# Sniffing Private Data Collection

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I've recently tried saving data in a hyperledger fabric network using its Private Data Collection. Everything worked out well except I have noticed a potential vulnerability.

I've done a block sniffer in Nodejs that will run as one of the legit peer in my channel. The block sniffer would attach a block event listener and display the content of every single block committed to the ledger.

Upon inspection, the data I want to store in the private data collection is masked in the read-write set (as intended), but I noticed that the arguments to any chaincode functions will still be publicly visible, and to my knowledge we can only store data in private data collection through a chaincode.

Does that mean that the data that we are going to store in the private data collection is, in fact, not private since everyone can see it as arguments passed to the chaincode? or Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Private input should be passed as `transient`.

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/private-data/private-data.html

See the example in https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/private_data_tutorial.html#store-private-data where the argument to invoke includes at the end `--transient "{\"marble\":\"$MARBLE\"}"`.